# How to count for records with empty values in 3 colums

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm not a SQL Server 2008 expert, but this is what I'm trying to accomplish. Let's say that I have this table:

I want to count the records that don't have values in `col2, col3`, and `col4` where `col1=1`, I have tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    LEN(col2) > 1 OR LEN(col3) > 1 OR LEN(col4) > 1 AND col1 = '1'
```

But I get thousands of records. If any of you guys can help or point me in the right direction I'll appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "empty" mean? NULL? Empty string? Something else?

Comment: And has higher precedence than or. Your `WHERE` is equivalent to `LEN(col2) > 1 OR LEN(col3) > 1 OR (LEN(col4) > 1 AND col1 = '1')`

Comment: I apologize, but you are right NULL, EMPTY menas different things, lets say that there are no characters on the column.

Comment: In the first place, if you want records with no values, you want LEN(col1)=0 not >1. Also, as Aaron says, you need to specify what 'empty' means. If the column is NULL, I wouldn't use LEN. LEN of a NULL field returns NULL, not 0.

Comment: So if there are no characters in the column, it can be NULL or an empty string. These are different things. Can it be both, or just one?

Comment: Just One, empty string...

Comment: I just tried the LEN(col2)=0 aproach and I get a count of 0, Melanie, theres no NULL values on this table, just empty string.

Comment: See Lighthart's answer below. If you substitue col2 = '' for col2 IS NULL, and do the same for col3 and col4, AND use the parentheses as suggested, does that help? If not, please post your exact query with those changes

Comment: SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM table
WHERE 
(
   col2 IS NULL 
OR col3 IS NULL
OR col4 IS NULL 
)
AND col1='1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the operator precedence at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx

'AND' gets evaluated before 'OR' so your example looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    LEN(col2) > 1 OR LEN(col3) > 1 OR ( LEN(col4) > 1 AND col1 = '1' )
```

That is a pretty open selection.  You said:

> I want to count the records that don't have values

But your code is counting the records that DO have values.  So maybe you want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1)
FROM table
WHERE col1 = '1' AND
(  col2 IS NULL
OR col3 IS NULL
OR col4 IS NULL
)
```

You can show data that has values when you say:

WHERE LEN(col2) > 0

But if col2 IS NULL, then LEN(col2) IS NULL as well.  Not zero.

If your string is '' instead of NULL, then you could check the LENgth:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1)
FROM table
WHERE col1 = '1' AND
(  LEN(col2) = 0
OR LEN(col3) = 0
OR LEN(col4) = 0
)
```

And of course, if you really did intend to see values that were not empty:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1)
FROM table
WHERE col1 = '1' AND
(  LEN(col2) > 0
OR LEN(col3) > 0
OR LEN(col4) > 0
)
```

Also in your example, you said the LEN() was > 1.  Did you mean greater than 1 or zero?

Comment: Kenvro, that worked!, I was breaking my head on how to do this, thanks. also thanks to everyone that posted an answer, next time I'll try to be more specific on my questions.

Comment: It's probably not a problem in this case, but it's good to be aware that LEN doesn't count trailing spaces.  So, LEN(' ') = 0. This would only be a problem for you if you didn't want to consider a column with only spaces to be "empty".

Answer (score 2):

Just add more WHERE conditions

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  col2 IS NULL
  AND  col3 IS NULL 
  AND  col4 IS NULL 
  AND  col1='1'
```

Also your example language contradicts our sample code.  You may want instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  
  (    col2 IS NULL
  OR   col3 IS NULL 
  OR   col4 IS NULL 
  )
  AND  col1='1'
```

Comment: Lighthart, Thanks for your answer, I have tried that and if I use IS NULL dont work because is an empty string value. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  
  (    COALESCE(col2,'')=''
  OR   COALESCE(col3,'')=''
  OR   COALESCE(col4,'')=''
  )
  AND  col1='1'
```